# Node JS Heroku Build Error - 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I hadn't made any changes to my build (all the same dependencies) and yet all of a sudden now it's crashing when I push to my staging environment.

At first I was getting this -

```
2022-02-10T03:42:49.245470+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.245471+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311176+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311177+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311177+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311178+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311181+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/buffer_list'
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311181+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311182+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311182+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311182+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/util/logger.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311182+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/logger.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311183+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/newrelic/index.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311183+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311186+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311190+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311190+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311190+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311190+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:72:18)       
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311192+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311192+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311192+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311192+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js',
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311193+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js',
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311193+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/util/logger.js',
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311193+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/logger.js',
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311194+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/newrelic/index.js',
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311194+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server.js'
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311194+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-02-10T03:42:49.311194+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

So I thought maybe Heroku was cracking down on newrelic or something so I uninstalled that and then now I'm getting -

```
2022-02-10T04:17:31.000789+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2022-02-10T04:17:31.000789+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222303+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222304+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222305+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222305+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222306+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../../helpers/getConstructorName'
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222309+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222310+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222310+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222310+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222310+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222311+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222311+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222312+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222312+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222312+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222326+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:12:28)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222326+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222326+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222326+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222327+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222327+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222327+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222328+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222328+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js',
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222328+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js',
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222329+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js',
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222329+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js',
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222329+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server.js'
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222330+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-02-10T04:17:31.222330+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I tried cleaning npm cache, removing node_modules folder, and npm install with both errors but they persisted.  It also boots up no issue when I use npm start on my commandline, so something is up with Heroku?  Any recommendations for what else I should try?  Could it be the node version? I'm not 100% on this but I feel like before in the build I would notice Node 14.x and now it's 16.x.

Also, package.json -

```
{
  "name": "CSQ",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.6",
    "@slack/events-api": "^3.0.1",
    "@slack/web-api": "^6.5.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "base64-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "concat-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "excel4node": "^1.7.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "googleapis": "^89.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "intuit-oauth": "^4.0.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.12",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.27.0",
    "node-quickbooks": "^2.0.39",
    "pdf-forms": "^0.1.1",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.0",
    "pdfform.js": "^1.0.14",
    "plotly": "^1.0.6",
    "popsicle": "^10.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: (a) What do you mean by "removing node_modules folder"? Are you just deleting it locally? Is that folder committed to your repository? (b) Please show your `package.json`.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for having a look, updated post with package.json.  Yes, deleting it locally; no not committed as it's in .gitignore.  Good point, and I've got to figure out how to do that for a heroku app; I just deleted the app and created a new one so fresh build on Heroku.

Comment: To be clear: your `node_modules/` should _not_ be committed. It's good that you have it ignored.

Comment: Ha thanks @Chris I try to follow the tutorials :) so you think it could be the node version or something?

Comment: I don't see a build script or a start script in your `package.json`. Do you have a `Procfile`?

Comment: @Chris I'm pretty sure no. You can see this get executed on start - "node server.js"

Answer (score 0):

Fix came from Heroku article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

This part -

```
Don’t check in generated directories
The app’s node_modules directory is generated at build time from the dependencies listed in package.json and the lockfile. Therefore, node_modules (and other generated directories like bower_components) shouldn’t be included in source control. Check with the following:

git ls-files | grep node_modules
If there are results, then instruct git to stop tracking node_modules:

echo "node_modules" >> .gitignore
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -am 'untracked node_modules'
```

That did it.  I don't really get why that did it when node_modules is in my gitignore AND when I've had this project up for almost a year without having this issue , but it did.